# Order confirmation E-mail is not working

Tags: magento

Order Confirmation Email is not sending on user's email id whenever user place an order in magento store? Help me out from there?

Comment: Check if email sending is working on your host and on selected email address (try to change it too). Try any example from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Method which send emails in magento is here: Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento version 1.9.1 order emails are sent via the cron and not directly on order placement.

Simply set-up the cron on your server to something like:

```
# for debugging purposes only:
MAILTO=your.user@your.server.com

*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

And then emails should be sent out after a max of 5 mins.